# Drupal field values and longtext

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-schema

Long time mysql/php user, first time Drupal user. Actually, I'm not doing the Drupal development (I'm just using the database to pull in some data to a separate application), and I'm just trying to figure out if this is how it's supposed to work:

Every one of the "value" fields in the `content_type_*` tables is of type `LONGTEXT`. This seems a bit nuts to me (not to mention a pain to have to `CAST` a lot of values if I don't want a string), but is this how Drupal works? Or does (should?) the developer have specified a "type" in some way in the Drupal admin.

Clearly the appeal of Drupal is its modularity and the fact that it seems to "make the database for you", but I'm not liking the schema it's producing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CCK does that because CCK can't know how long the values you'll permit will be (especially when it's a free-entry textarea). Any Drupal dev who knows enough to want to change it from a `LONGTEXT` to something that better suits that particular field has the know-how to go into the DB and tweak it themselves.

Drupal does a lot for you, but there are certain things best left up to the developer. This is one of them, as is the related issue of adding indexes to certain CCK `content_type_*` fields you're likely to filter on.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I figured that was something you knew. Yeah, those `content_` tables are built by the Content Construction Kit (which is mostly moving into core Drupal with version 7).